# How do I replace the nth occurence of a match when using Look Ahead and Look Behind Regex pattern

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a way to do a replacement of some image paths in code using regex function. 
Ultimately, I'll be using a text batch processing tool called "TextCrawler" to do these substitutions but at this point I'm interested in knowing how to use regex matches to specify a particular occurrence. I was not able to get any [quantifiers](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) to allow me to do this.

I'm using `(?<=@heroImageURL = ").+(?=")|(?<=@productImageURL = ").+(?=")` to do a replacement for the image paths and this regex finds all the image paths.
However, I like to know how to target a nth specific instance of a particular variable's value.
In the example below I have 2 different variables for each brand condition. 
When I want to substitute, I don't want each possible variable to receive the same value substitute so I need help with applying specificity.

Each variable will vary in it's value based on the brandName and this process will be iterative over several different files so I'm looking to ultimately put the Find and Replacement values that contain the Regex pattern and Substitution into a comma separated list that I will feed into TextCrawler for the replacement.

Here is my [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/0tMLaS/2/)

```
IF @brandName == "A" THEN
   set @heroImageURL = "http://www.image.com/a9230239u230.jpg"
   set @productImageURL = "http://www.image.com/A29200923.jpg"
ELSEIF @brandName == "B" THEN
   set @heroImageURL = "http://www.image.com/b2389823u238.jpg"
   set @productImageURL = "http://www.image.com/B22392029.jpg"
ELSEIF @brandName == "C" THEN
   set @heroImageURL = "http://www.image.com/c23892389289.jpg"
   set @productImageURL = "http://www.image.com/C49309934.jpg"
ELSEIF @brandName == "D" THEN
   set @heroImageURL = "http://www.image.com/d23423892833.jpg"
   set @productImageURL = "http://www.image.com/D09349409.jpg"
ELSEIF @brandName == "E" THEN
   set @heroImageURL = "http://www.image.com/e22823889899.jpg"
   set @productImageURL = "http://www.image.com/E22092309.jpg"
ELSE
   set @heroImageURL = "http://www.image.com/e22823889899.jpg"
   set @productImageURL = "http://www.image.com/E22092309.jpg"
ENDIF
```

Comment: So you're trying to match the nth instance of **either** `heroImageURL` or `productImageURL`?

Comment: It's also useful to know which language or regex engine you're using. Also `.+(?=")` could give you incorrect results.

Comment: Something like `\A.*?(?:@heroImageURL\s*=\s*"[^"]+".*?){4}@heroImageURL\s*=\s*"\K[^"]+(?=")` will work for some regex engines. This particular regex matching the fifth instance.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I posted the regex101 link so I thought the Regex Flavor was evident. To be specific...PCRE (PHP) but toggling to JavaScript it adjust to work as well. I tried what you pasted above within my regex101.com link as the regex expression and for me it did not select the variable's value inside the quotes for the 5th instance for both heroImageURL and productImageURL. Are you seeing different? Is your regex working within my regex101.com link?

Comment: sorry, set . to match newline characters

Comment: Does https://regex101.com/r/6uKOlM/1 work for you?

Comment: Wow! single line Thank you. It works great for PCRE(PHP) but not for Ecmascript/Javascript. I would love to know what to change to adjust to keep it valid in Javascript?

Comment: You can switch `\A` for `^` and only return first match (remove global flag). You'll also need to capture everything up to `\K` and use `$1` in replacement

Comment: Is there any way to do this without the \K....I just learned that TextCrawler doesn't support it. It's using .net regular expressions [link](https://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/board/viewtopic.php?t=1729)

Comment: Yes, my last comment explains this, but you capture everything up to `\K` and remove the `\K` token. `^(.*?(?:@heroImageURL\s*=\s*"[^"]+".*?){4}@heroImageURL\s*=\s*")[^"]+(?=")` then you replace with `$1something` - where `something` is your replacement.

Comment: Your regex is nothing short of brilliant! Thank you so much!